# Entering 'Ex' mode

Tags: vimrc

I've come across the following a few times accidentally (I think when pressing capital Q):

> Entering Ex mode.  Type "visual" to go to Normal mode.

It seems that `Ex` mode works almost identically to `:` mode so I was wondering if that's ever actually used?

Comment: @Biggybi yes, thank you I'll check that out. Out of curiosity, do you ever use `Ex` mode yourself?

Comment: I never found myself in a situation where I felt I needed it. I'm basically only aware of its existence.